# Erro ao criar controller usando o Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

No meu projeto de Cadastro de Funcionários tenho as seguintes pastas:

- MODEL
- CONTROLLERS
- DAL
- VIEWS

A partir do momento em que vou criar um *controller* usando o **Entity** que já me cria direto a minha *view* ele dá o erro:

> (Erro ao executar o gerador de código selecionado: 'Unrecognized
>   command or argument'(FuncionariosCadastros.DAL))

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "criar um controller usando o entity"? Está falando do _scaffolding_ padrão do Visual Studio?

Comment: O que você está usando? Entity Framework Core? Asp.Net Core?

Comment: Sim, Estou Seguindo este Tutorial  -- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#software-versions-used-in-the-tutorial -- A parte em que vou criar o Controle de Funcionario com o Entity gera esse erro, para que ele não reconhece minha Classe Context?

Comment: Estou usando o ASP .NET Core